# How does one implement adversarial examples in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I wanted to reproduce:

from the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6199.pdf. I was wondering, how does one actually implement this in pytorch? My main confusion is that for `loss_f` I am using a `torch.nn.CrossEntropy()` criterion for example. Do i just need to change the code that I already have from:

```
loss = criterion(outputs+r, labels)
loss.backward()
```

to:

```
loss = criterion(outputs+r, labels)
loss = loss + c * r.norm(2)
loss.backward()
```

or something along those lines (of course include r in the optimizer!). I know its not quite right cuz I did not explicitly show how I implemented `x+r` or the hypercube constraint but those are parts that I still need to figure out.

I think for the moment I want to focus first without the hypercube constraint. If we assume I am ok with going out of that is the above correct? I just want to know if:

```
loss = loss + c * r.norm(2)
```

works as it should.

---

Now if we do include the hypercube constraint how does my solution change? Is that were the "penalty function method" come into place?

---

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-one-implement-adversarial-examples-in-pytorch/15668

Comment: perhaps useful: https://github.com/akshaychawla/Adversarial-Examples-in-PyTorch

Answer (score 8):

This is how i did it. Hope that helps you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Nov 18 12:39:16 2016

@author: manojacharya
"""

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision import models,transforms
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn.functional as F
import json



normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                             std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     normalize])


def imshow(inp, title=None):
    """Imshow for Tensor."""
    plt.figure()
    inp = inp.data[0]
    inp = inp.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0))
    mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
    std = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    inp = std * inp + mean
    plt.imshow(inp)
    plt.axis('off')
    if title is not None:
        plt.title(title)

with open('imagenet.json') as f:
    imagenet_labels = json.load(f)

# In[model]:

model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False


def predict(img):
    pred_raw = model(img)
    pred = F.softmax(pred_raw)
    _,indices = torch.topk(pred,k=1)
    for ind in indices.data.numpy().ravel():
        print ("%.2f%% , class: %s , %s" %(100*pred.data[0][ind],str(ind),imagenet_labels[ind]))


# In[image ]:

peppers = imread("dog.jpg")
img =  imresize(peppers,(224,224))
imgtensor = transform(img)
imgvar = Variable(imgtensor.unsqueeze(0),requires_grad=False)
imgvard = Variable(imgtensor.unsqueeze(0),requires_grad=True)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([imgvard], lr = 0.1)
loss_fn =  nn.CrossEntropyLoss() 

label  =  torch.LongTensor(1)
#classify the object as this label
label[0] = 80
label = Variable(label)
eps = 2/255.0

#%% 
Nepochs = 50
print ("Starting ...........",predict(imgvar))

for epoch in range(Nepochs):     
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    pred_raw = model(imgvard)
    loss  =  loss_fn(pred_raw,label)

    diff = imgvard.data - imgvar.data
    imgvard.data = torch.clamp(torch.abs(diff),max=eps) + imgvar.data

    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print('epoch: {}/{}, loss: {}'.format(
                epoch + 1,Nepochs, loss.data[0]))
    predict(imgvard)
print('Finished Training')

#%%
imshow(imgvard)


#%%
plt.figure()
diffimg = diff[0].numpy()
diffimg = diffimg.transpose((1,2,0))
plt.imshow(diffimg)
```

Answer (score 4):

I will try to talk about adversarial examples in a  simple way. Basically, for a given example belonging to certain class C_1 , we want to modify this input by adding small value r in such a way that it doesnot change visually much but is classified with very high confidence to another class C_2. To do that you optmize the function:[image]

So ideally, we want r to be very small which is obtained by doing L1 regularization over r which is the first part of the equation. And the second term loss is the loss from classifying the input x + r to the new target class C_2. For each iteration while optimizing for loss,

```
                        x_t = x_(t-1) + r
```

Also make sure x+r is with some range of x i.e allow x to change within some very small range i.e maybe 0.0001.
This will give x_t which is an adversarial example to x.
I know its confusing but this is all you need to implement the above equation. Hope this helps.

Comment: do you have a small example that actually runs in pytorch?

Answer (score 1):

We opensourced (and is actively maintaining) the AdverTorch toolbox, an adversarial robustness toolbox based on PyTorch at https://github.com/BorealisAI/advertorch

Please have a look if interested.

https://github.com/BorealisAI/advertorch/blob/master/advertorch/attacks/lbfgs.py implements the LBFGS attack in that paper.